# Is it a good practice to depend on boolean operators returning one of their operands?

Tags: javascript

I often rely on the fact that in Javascript conditional operators do not return true or false but one of the arguments.

For example:

```
function(e){
    this.someotherfunction.apply(this, e.config || []); 
}
```

So far I have not come across any issues and when I tried to find out what Douglas Crockford (read JSLint) has to say about it, I haven't found any issue.

Are there any dangers in using this kind of syntax?

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any dangers in using this kind of syntax ?

No.

(As long as you and all other developers know what this code does...)

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly documented and works that way in [many dynamic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages). It is safe to use this construction and it is widely recognized.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is idiomatic JavaScript.

> Are there any dangers in using this kind of syntax?

You do have to be careful about knowing what the inputs are. e.g. if something expects a number, then you have to account for `0` being a false value.

Answer (score 1):

Only issue you may face is an angry developer saying they have a hard time reading it and would demand it to be rewritten as.

```
foo : function (e) {
    var config =  e.config || [];
    this.someotherfunction.apply(this,config); 
}
```

And yes, I have run into those angry developers.